# Is subdirectory in /usr/bin really forbidden by FHS

Tags: fhs, lintian

Lintian tag description:

> The Filesystem Hierarchy Standard forbids the installation of new directories in /usr/bin other than /usr/bin/mh.

However, all I can find the linked document is

> This is the primary directory of executable commands on the system.

This *allows* executable commands to go there, but it does not forbid anything. What paragraph doees Lintian refer to?

The reason I like to put a subdirectory there is that I have a wrapper script, that the user uses instead of the binary, and I want the wrapper script to work without changes when "installing" the program. In short, the script looks like

```
options=()
debug=0
mode="rel"
for option in "$@"; do
    if [ "$option" == "--debug" ]; then
        debug=1
        mode="dbg"
    else
        options+=("$option")
    fi
done

current_dir=$(dirname "`readlink -f "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"`")
binary="$current_dir"/__anja_"$mode"_"$arch"/anja

if [ $debug -eq 1 ]; then
    gdb --args "$binary" "${options[@]}"
else
    exec "$binary" "${options[@]}"
fi
```

where `arch` is deduced from `/proc/cpuinfo`. The build system emits the binary in the directory `__anja_"$mode"_"$arch"`, in the project root directory.

Yes, the correct place for the real binaries is `/usr/libexec`, but then the script must be changed during the installation procedure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Section 4.4.2 of the FHS, version 3.0](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch04s04.html), specifically states

> There must be no subdirectories in `/usr/bin`.

Since you’re using Lintian, I suppose you’re targeting Debian or a derivative; in such an environment, the appropriate location for your binaries is a package-specific subdirectory of `/usr/lib`. Debian and its derivatives don’t use `/usr/libexec`.